# Porque o input submit não fica no mesmo tamanho que os outros inputs?

Tags: html, css

É uma duvida que estou tendo e não estou conseguindo sair daqui e se você conseguir me ajudar pode ter certeza que vai estar ajudando muito na evolução do conhecimento de alguém que está aprendendo.

-HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Sistema de Cadastro</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="_css\estilo-cadastro.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="corpo-form">

        <h1>Entrar</h1>

        <form>
            <input type="email" placeholder="Usuário">
            <input type="password" placeholder="Senha">
            <input type="submit" value="Entrar">
            <a href="">Clique aqui para cadastrar-se!</a>
        </form>

    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

-CSS

```
*{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}


input{
    display: block;
    height: 50px;
    width: 400px;
    margin: 5px;
    border-radius: 30px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    font-size: 16pt;
    padding: 10px 20px;
}

div#corpo-form{
    /*background-color: red;*/
    width: 420px;
    margin: 150px auto 0px auto;
}
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Como assim mesmo tamanho, @LYNTT ? Eles são botões de tipos diferentes, natural não terem tamanhos idênticos. Um é pra texto, outro para senha e o submit.

Comment: Se você quiser colocar estilizações diferentes para cada um eles, você deve atribuir um id ou classe para cada um deles e estilizar. Exemplo: <input type="submit" value="Entrar" id="entrar">. Para estilizar ficaria input#enviar{seu código de estilização css aqui dentro}. Nesse caso, só o input submit pegaria as estilizações.

Comment: Por eles serem botões de tipos diferentes, tem características de estilizações próprias. De uma olhada nesse exemplo. De longe não é a maneira mais correta de se fazer, mas pelo menos você terá um ideia de como se trabalhar utilizando os ids como seletores e como estilizar cada um deles de forma individual. https://jsfiddle.net/xz8uthd5/

Comment: Obrigado @Gambi por me ajudar na solução do meu problema, agora posso partir para concluir esse pequeno projeto.

Comment: Mas, @LYNTT. Essa não é a melhor maneira de se resolver isso. Tanto que nem coloquei como resposta, e sim como comentário e postei o código no fiddle. Dá uma olhadinha melhor em CSS. Sou iniciante também, estamos no mesmo barco em busca de cada vez mais conhecimento. Que a força esteja com você!

Comment: Entendido, que a força esteja com você também @Gambi.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Isso acontece porque o botão (tanto botão com `input` quanto botão com `button`) tem como padrão a propriedade `box-sizing` com valor `border-box`:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O valor `border-box` impede que o `padding` e a borda do elemento sejam somados à largura e altura do elemento, por isso o seu botão fica menor que os campos de texto, que possuem como padrão o valor `content-box` (você pode saber mais sobre o `box-sizing` [nesta documentação](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing)).

Para resolver isso, basta você alterar o `box-sizing` do botão para `content-box`, que tudo irá ficar com o mesmo tamanho, pois o botão irá somar o `padding` e o `border` às suas dimensões:

```css
*{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

input{
    display: block;
    height: 50px;
    width: 400px;
    margin: 5px;
    border-radius: 30px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    font-size: 16pt;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    box-sizing: content-box;
}

div#corpo-form{
    /*background-color: red;*/
    width: 420px;
    margin: 150px auto 0px auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="corpo-form">

  <h1>Entrar</h1>

  <form>
      <input type="email" placeholder="Usuário">
      <input type="password" placeholder="Senha">
      <input type="submit" value="Entrar">
      <a href="">Clique aqui para cadastrar-se!</a>
  </form>

</div>
```

Caso você não queira alterar esse padrão para todos os botões, basta criar uma classe específica só para esse botão. Por exemplo, `.contBox`:

```css
*{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

input{
    display: block;
    height: 50px;
    width: 400px;
    margin: 5px;
    border-radius: 30px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    font-size: 16pt;
    padding: 10px 20px;
}

.contBox{
   box-sizing: content-box;
}

div#corpo-form{
    /*background-color: red;*/
    width: 420px;
    margin: 150px auto 0px auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="corpo-form">

  <h1>Entrar</h1>

  <form>
      <input type="email" placeholder="Usuário">
      <input type="password" placeholder="Senha">
      <input class="contBox" type="submit" value="Entrar">
      <a href="">Clique aqui para cadastrar-se!</a>
  </form>

</div>
```

### Problema

Outro problema é que você definiu a div `id="corpo-form"` com `420px` de largura e os inputs com `400px + 20px de padding + 1px de borda`. Somando tudo dará `442px`, ultrapassando `42px` a largura da div (sem contar o `margin` de `5px` que colocou).

Para ficar certinho, altere o `width` do input para `442px` e o `margin` para `margin: 5px;` para que tenha margem apenas no top e bottom dos inputs.

## Solução ainda melhor

Para não se preocupar com a largura dos elementos e que eles ocupem a largura total da div, além do `box-sizing: content-box`, coloque `width: 100%`. E na div principal reduza o `width` para `400px` (ou `420px` se quiser):

```css
*{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

input{
    display: block;
    height: 50px;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 5px 0;
    border-radius: 30px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    font-size: 16pt;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    box-sizing: content-box;
}

div#corpo-form{
    /*background-color: red;*/
    width: 400px;
    margin: 150px auto 0px auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="corpo-form">

  <h1>Entrar</h1>

  <form>
      <input type="email" placeholder="Usuário">
      <input type="password" placeholder="Senha">
      <input type="submit" value="Entrar">
      <a href="">Clique aqui para cadastrar-se!</a>
  </form>

</div>
```